# Issue trying to form ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, retrofit2

I know this is probably a simple issue, but I am confused as to why my `ArrayAdapter` isn't working. I am using retrofit to call back data, and I am getting the data back, but when I try to add that data into an ArrayAdapter I get the following error in ide:

```
Error:(49, 37) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(HomeActivity,int,OpenPulls)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OpenPulls cannot be converted to int)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,OpenPulls[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OpenPulls cannot be converted to OpenPulls[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<OpenPulls>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OpenPulls cannot be converted to List<OpenPulls>)
```

I'm sure the resolution is probably right there, but I can't see it. Here is my code.

HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  public CdenApi cdenAPI;
  private ArrayAdapter<OpenPulls> openPullsAdapter;
  public OpenPulls openpullsObject;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    cdenAPI = ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getCdenAPI();

    cdenAPI.getOpenPulls(cdenAPI.REQ_WITH, cdenAPI.CONT_TYPE,
            ((MyApplication) this.getApplication()).getAuthToken())
            .enqueue(new Callback<OpenPulls>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<OpenPulls> call, Response<OpenPulls> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                       openpullsObject = response.body();

                        openPullsAdapter =
                                new ArrayAdapter<OpenPulls>(HomeActivity.this, 0, openpullsObject) {
                                    @Override
                                    public View getView(int position,
                                                        View convertView,
                                                        ViewGroup parent){
                                        Currentpull currentItem = openpullsObject.currentpulls.get(position);

                                        if(convertView == null) {
                                            convertView = getLayoutInflater()
                                                    .inflate(R.layout.join_pulls_item, null, false);
                                        }

                                        TextView pullTo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.storeToJoinTV);
                                        TextView pullFrom = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.storeFromJoinTV);

                                        pullTo.setText(currentItem.to.toString());
                                        pullFrom.setText(currentItem.from.toString());

                                        return convertView;
                                    }
                                };

                        final ListView itemsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.openPullsLV);
                        itemsList.setAdapter(openPullsAdapter);

                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Pulls returned Home.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Pulls not returned Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<OpenPulls> call, Throwable t) {
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

  }

}
```

OpenPulls.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class OpenPulls {

  @SerializedName("currentpulls")
  @Expose
  public ArrayList<Currentpull> currentpulls = null;

  }
```

Currentpull.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Currentpull {

  @SerializedName("id")
  @Expose
  public Integer id;
  @SerializedName("created_at")
  @Expose
  public String createdAt;
  @SerializedName("updated_at")
  @Expose
  public String updatedAt;
  @SerializedName("pull_id")
  @Expose
  public Integer pullId;
  @SerializedName("box_count")
  @Expose
  public Integer boxCount;
  @SerializedName("status")
  @Expose
  public String status;
  @SerializedName("total_quantity")
  @Expose
  public Integer totalQuantity;
  @SerializedName("to")
  @Expose
  public String to;
  @SerializedName("from")
  @Expose
  public String from;

}
```

I just need to know what I'm doing wrong in trying to parse the data and get it passed to the `ListView`.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: What about `LogCat`, do you have it?

Comment: I'm not actually able to build with this ArrayAdapter in my code. The build fails and I get the message above from Gradle

Comment: Show lines 49, 37.

Comment: `openPullsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<OpenPulls>(HomeActivity.this, 0, openpullsObject) {` This is the line that is showing the error, specifically the parameters.

Comment: Try with HomeActivity.class

Comment: that didn't fix it, got a new error that said the class couldn't be couldn't be converted into  Context

Comment: `OpenPulls cannot be converted to int` and `OpenPulls cannot be converted to List<OpenPulls>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154944/discussion-between-mtrueblood-and-stanojkovic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error:

```
Error:(49, 37) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(HomeActivity,int,OpenPulls)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OpenPulls cannot be converted to int)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,OpenPulls[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OpenPulls cannot be converted to OpenPulls[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<OpenPulls>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OpenPulls cannot be converted to List<OpenPulls>)
```

The constructor needs the last parameter as int, or `OpenPulls[]` or `List<OpenPulls>`. But you pass an object to the constructor:

```
openpullsObject = response.body();

openPullsAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<OpenPulls>(HomeActivity.this, 0, 
                          openpullsObject) {...}
```

So, you need to pass the correct parameter.